# How can I read values of json with multiple level in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json, multi-level

I have the following code to read a Json and store some values into an array:

```
<?php
$json = '[{
        "provider_id":1,
        "nro_chart":1,
        "control": {
            "color": "blue",
            "total_value": 21.5,
            "car_id": 421118
        }
    },
    {
        "control": {
            "color": "green",
            "total_value": 25,
            "car_id": 421119
        }
    },
    {
        "control": {
            "color": "red",
            "total_value": 18,
            "car_id": 421519
        }
    }
]';

$j = json_decode($data);
$result = [];
foreach ($j as $item) {
    array_push($result,[
        'total_value' => $item->control->total_value,
        'car_id' => $item->control->car_id
    ]);
}
```

Now I need to get the two values that are outside of "control" like "provider_id" and "nro_chart" inside a variable.

Comment: _PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: data_

Comment: What do you mean "get the two values" "inside a variable"?  Do you mean store them within the same subarray?  Or declare `$provider_id` and `$nro_chart` independent of the generated array?  This detail will be important to future SO readers that visit this page.  Please improve your question by posting your exact expected output.

Comment: Are `provider_id` and `nro_chart` always in the first subarray?  or might they be anywhere in the array?  Is there only one set of these values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON contains an array of one element, so to access `provider_id` and `nro_chart`, get the first element and directly access the properties:

```
$j = json_decode($json);
var_dump($j[0]->provider_id); // /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trello/up.php:28:int 1
var_dump($j[0]->nro_chart); // /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/trello/up.php:28:int 1
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/20Q38)

Or, within that same `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($j as $item) {
    array_push($result,[
        'total_value' => $item->control->total_value,
        'car_id' => $item->control->car_id
    ]);
    if (isset($item->provider_id)) {
        var_dump($item->provider_id);
    }
    if (isset($item->nro_chart)) {
        var_dump($item->nro_chart);
    }
}
```

Be sure to check if the property is set for that element with `isset()` first.

Comment: Im Getting "Trying to get property of non-object in line..." that is in the line of var_dump($j[0]->provider_id);

Comment: Did you check the demo? Can you post the code you're using to 3v4l.org or something?

Comment: Yes I check the demo... the only diference is that the json came from URL.. with: $getJson = file_get_contents('php://input'); ... but cant read that two values..

Comment: I see, the JSON response is different then. Use the second example, in the first one I asume the first element has those properties, in your actual response it probably doesn't. So, in the second example it checks if the property exists in the current element so you shouldn't have that problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

will transform your json string to an associative array.
so now you can use : $item['provider_id'].

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to modify the array and declare the two extra variables with less iterated functions.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ikilp))

```
$array = json_decode($json,true);  // decode as array because that is what you are generating in the result

$provider_id=$array[0]['provider_id'];
$nro_chart=$array[0]['nro_chart'];

foreach($array as $index=>&$subarray){  // modify $subarray by reference
    $subarray=['total_value'=>$subarray['control']['total_value'],'car_id'=>$subarray['control']['car_id']];  // overwrite each subarray using the first two elements from deeper "control" subarray
}

echo "provider_id = $provider_id\n";  // display integer value
echo "nro_chart = $nro_chart\n";      // display integer value
var_export($array);                   // display updated array
```

Output:

```
provider_id = 1
nro_chart = 1
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'total_value' => 21.5,
    'car_id' => 421118,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'total_value' => 25,
    'car_id' => 421119,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'total_value' => 18,
    'car_id' => 421519,
  ),
)
```